# Remove duplicate </td> closing tags in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on an [e-commerce website](http://qplzf.xjfha.servertrust.com/category-s/1814.htm) that has a lot of invalid HTML markup including the following. This is a hosted e-commerce application that I do not have access to its source. I can only edit one single template file but do not have access to where the actual table is generated.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to remove the "duplicate" closing **`</td>`** tags?

Comment: The best way would be to find where the duplicate `</td>` is coming from and remove it.  What code generates the table?

Comment: Remove it from the source, not with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is a DOM manipulation library written in JavaScript. It manipulates the DOM after markup has been parsed and loaded into memory and rendered. At such time, no extra closing tags would be present--the browser will have dealt with it. If you want to remove them from a string of HTML before inserting into the DOM, your question would be better asked if you replaced "jQuery" with "JavaScript" and made it clear that this is what you're wanting. In the end, however, you don't want to deal with this in JS, I assure you. Fix the source.

Comment: I added some comment to explain why I don't have access to the source that generates the table; hence resorting to Javascript.

Comment: The obvious has already been mentioned. Have you tried using jQuery `$('td').find('td').unwrap();` Example http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: With your new info explaining that you cannot modify the source, you need to provide some code which shows how you're obtaining the offending markup via JS. If you're not, and are only concerned that the server is sending bad markup to the browser, let it go. The browser will deal with it.

Comment: @JAAulde Actually he can do it with jq, using `.html()` method copying text or whatever from tds, then making some sort of object with his table structure, removing old table from html, and then generating new one and appending it to his ... whatever)) But this is crazy))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do this with jquery, this plugin will do it for you: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/

If you run your sample code through the [demo page](http://www.antix.co.uk/Content/Demos/jQuery-htmlClean/Test.htm), this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

becomes:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't remove such closing tags only. By the way, most browsers do automatically correct closing tags.

If you really need to remove, you must remove such unnecessary code manually yourself directly from the source code.

Comment: I added some comment to explain why I don't have access to the source that generates the table; hence resorting to Javascript.